# Use SELECT subquery within UNION

Tags: sql, join, subquery, inner-join, union

I have two tables:

Table 1

[image: Table 1]

Table 2

[image: Table 2]

I am trying to write a query to SELECT all records for both tables, using UNION (columns ID, Date and Amount). The tables are linked by ID. When selecting the records in Table 2 however during the UNION, if the related ID in Table 1 has a True or False value of TRUE, I want to change the Date of the Table 2 record to the date in Table 1, ultimate acheiving this:

[image: Output]

Is this possible?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd query of UNION ALL should be a join of the tables:

```
select id, date, amount 
from Table1
union all
select 
  t2.id,
  case when t1.trueorfalse = 'TRUE' then t1.date else t2.date end
  t2.amount
from Table2 t2 inner join Table1 t1
on t1.id = t2.id
```

The `CASE` expression will return either the date from Table1 or from Table2.
If your database supports the Boolean data type maybe you should use `TRUE` instead of `'TRUE'`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a convenient place to use a lateral join, if your database supports it:

```
select v.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id cross join lateral
     (values (t1.id, (case when t1.true_or_false = 'true' then t2.date else t1.date end), t1.amount),
             (t2.id, t2.date, t2.amount)
     ) v(id, date, amount);
```